# OpenLDAP user group membership integrity

Tags: ldap, openldap

In OpenLDAP a user has membership in a group. Suppose one deletes the user. In the member attribute of the group the user remains. Is this considered an integrity violation? Is there a means to "autoremove" group membership.

I am using OpenLDAP 2.4 with cn=config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the referential integrity overlay. It will take care of not only this situation but also the case where the DN of a user is renamed.